Use of Datadog and Twilio webhook to send multiple text messages
I want to use Twilio to send text messages to multiple numbers at once after an alert on datadog. I however can only seem to make it work to send it to one number using the following payload:
{
"To": "$TO",
"From": "$FROM",
"Body": "Test message"
}

With $FROM and $TO being one (but different) number.
Can someone advise?
I have also tried
"To": "$TO"

With $TO being multiple numbers.
And:
"To": ["$TO1", "$TO2"]

And:
"To": "$TO1,$TO2"

With $TO1 and $TO2 being single numbers.
For all of which I expected two messages to be sent to two different numbers

The Twilio API doesn't support multiple recipients by default. For this case you need to use Twilio Notify, then pass each phone number as a ToBinding param. To enable this use case via Datadog webhooks, the out-of-the-box Twilio integration likely won't work. You need to have some endpoint you can hit to trigger Twilio Notify. Another option would be to use something like a Twilio Function that forwards one SMS message to multiple recipients (for example), then invoke that function from the webhook.
